# How to add dummy variables into xreg when modeling time series with multiple seasonality using fourier terms

Tags: r

I am trying to forecast daily calls number. Have daily data (from 2015) which display weekly and annual seasonality.

I have tried Dynamic harmonic regression with ARIMA errors. This model significantly under predict call numbers for Bank holidays so I created number of dummy variables: New Year, Early May Bank Holiday, Christmas etc. But this does not work.

```
ft <- fourier(calls, K=c(3,10))

model1<- auto.arima(calls, seasonal=FALSE, lambda=0,
                xreg=cbind(ft, NY, GoodFriday, EasterMonday,EarlyMayBH, 
                     SpringBH,ChristmasEve, ChristDay, BoxingDay, NYEve))

model1_forc <- forecast(model1, 
                   xreg=cbind(ft,
                              NY=c(1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0), 
                              GoodFriday=c(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0), 

EasterMonday=c(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0),
                              EarlyMayBH=c(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0),
                              SpringBH=c(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0),

ChristmasEve=c(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0),
                              ChristDay=c(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0),
                              BoxingDay=c(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0),
                              NYEve=c(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0)))




autoplot(model1_forc)
summary(model1_forc)
```

I got forecast but not very good one.

Comment: In the title you ask how to add dummy variables, but you clearly know how to do that. So are you asking how to improve the predictions of this model?